# Replace part of regular expression and keep prefix/postfix

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I was trying to replace some strings in a file using **sed** and came accross an issue.

I have the following strings:

```
TEMPLATE_MODULE
TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR
TEMPLATE_MORE_ERR
```

I would like to replace *TEMPLATE_MODULE* with some string and all strings that start with *TEMPLATE* and end with *ERR* with a different string, as follows:

```
TEMPLATE_MODULE   ---> NEW_MODULE_NAME
TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR ---> NEW_MODULE_NAME_SOME_ERR
TEMPLATE_MORE_ERR ---> NEW_MODULE_NAME_MORE_ERR
```

The replacement of TEMPLATE_MODULE is easy:

```
find . -type f -print -exec sed -i "s/TEMPLATE_MODULE/NEW_MODULE_NAME/g" {} +
```

Though I don't know how to handle the other part. If I look for strings starting with *TEMPLATE_** , I would also catch *TEMPLATE_MODULE*.

I also want to keep the *SOME_ERR* or *MORE_ERR* postfix so this solution would not work:

```
find . -type f -print -exec sed -i "s/TEMPLATE_.*_ERR$/NEW_MODULE_NAME/g" {} +
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have GNU sed? output `sed --version`?

Comment: Note that `.*` is a regex global match and not a ordinary glob expansion. You need to enable `-r` to support it, which is available only in `GNU sed`

Comment: I'm using GNU sed 4.2.2

Comment: What is the replacement pattern for your second set of strings?

Comment: @Inian you don't need `-r` or `-E` for `.*`... by default, `sed` would use BRE

Comment: @Sundeep : fair point, wanted to use -r to enable anchors for matching.

Comment: @Inian even anchors `^` and `$` do not need ERE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this sample input

```
$ cat ip.txt 
foo
TEMPLATE_MODULE
TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR
TEMPLATE_MORE_ERR
TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR xyz
```

Use multiple `s` commands and capture groups

```
$ sed -E 's/\bTEMPLATE_MODULE\b/NEW_MODULE_NAME/g; s/\bTEMPLATE\w*(_(SOME|MORE)_ERR)\b/NEW_MODULE_NAME\1/g' ip.txt 
foo
NEW_MODULE_NAME
NEW_MODULE_NAME_SOME_ERR
NEW_MODULE_NAME_MORE_ERR
NEW_MODULE_NAME_SOME_ERR xyz
```

- `\b` is for word boundaries. `\bcat\b` will match only `cat` and won't match `scat` or `cater`
- `s/\bTEMPLATE_MODULE\b/NEW_MODULE_NAME/g` will replace `TEMPLATE_MODULE` with `NEW_MODULE_NAME`
- `s/\bTEMPLATE\w*(_(SOME|MORE)_ERR)\b/NEW_MODULE_NAME\1/g` will replace `TEMPLATE` followed by zero or more word characters ending with `_SOME_ERR` or `_MORE_ERR` with `NEW_MODULE_NAME` and the captured string
- Solution is for `GNU sed`, not sure about portability with other implementations

Comment: Thanks! What does `\1` mean?

Comment: @Vardit that will have the captured group.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "TEMPLATE_MODULE" and "TEMPLATE_" are literal, but "SOME_ERR" and "MORE_ERR" are placeholders, the following seems possible.

```
sed "s/TEMPLATE\(_MODULE\)*/NEW_MODULE_NAME/"
```

I recommend to play with this as a bare sed line, then, if it is OK, integrate it into your commandline.

I think this code does not make more assumptions on occurrences and spellings than your own code.
However, you probably want to use "anchoring" in order to not accidentally replace "SOMEOTHERTEMPLATE_" etc.

To start you off on that here is a modified version:

```
sed "s/\bTEMPLATE\(_MODULE\)*/NEW_MODULE_NAME/"
```

I recommend to try that with:

```
TEMPLATE_MODULE  
TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR  
TEMPLATE_MORE_ERR  
OTHER_TEMPLATE_MODULE  
OTHER_TEMPLATE_SOME_ERR
```